# Full viewport images like on medium.com

Tags: image, css, viewport

How does Medium do full viewport images like in this [example](https://medium.com/art-of-product-design/aad5babee2f7)? (Not the header image, but the first image of the guy with his hands out).

I see that they use background-image and other css3 properties like this:

```
<div class="section-background-image" style="background-image: url(https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/700/gradv/29/81/40/1*vd1EjIG6xUWgqcX9uQLS6g.jpeg);"></div>

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100vh;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

But when I do it, it doesn't work. I'm guessing they also use javascript

Answer (score 0):

try putting your background image in your css

```
   background-image:url('../images/..');
```

and

```
   WIdth:100%;height:100%;
```

remove

```
   right: 0;
```

Comment: It doesnt work if there are multiple full viewport images, as the position absolute puts all of them at the top

Answer (score 0):

use the viewport width and height properties after setting the viewport to device-width, like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

And your css:

```
width:100vw; height:100vh;
```